# how to implement two button click activity in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, outlook, outlook-addin

i have a ribbon xml where on click of button i have to open two different windows form for respective button but i am not able to define two different button click function in same file.
xml :i having two button 
and code is

```c
STDMETHOD(ButtonClicked)(IDispatch* ribbon)
    {//MessageBoxW(NULL,L"Button Clicked!",L"NativeAddin",MB_OK);
        NativeAddIn::ApplicationConfiguration ^appConfigurationform = gcnew NativeAddIn::ApplicationConfiguration();
        appConfigurationform->ShowDialog();
        return S_OK;
    }
STDMETHOD(ButtonClicked)(IDispatch* ribbon)
    {
        //MessageBoxW(NULL,L"Button Clicked!",L"NativeAddin",MB_OK);
        NativeAddIn::Helpme ^helpmeobj = gcnew NativeAddIn::Helpme();
        helpmeobj->ShowDialog();
        return S_OK;
    }
```

how can i write two function on button click .
while executing code above Error coming is :

> HRESULT CConnect::ButtonClicked(IDispatch *)' : member function already defined or declared.

```xml
<button id="GoToAppConfiguration" size="large" label="Application Configuration" imageMso="AutoArchiveSettings" onAction="ButtonClicked"/> 
<button id="GoToAppHelp" size="large" label="Help" imageMso="CreateReportFromWizard" onAction="ButtonClicked"/>
```

please help....

Comment: <button id="GoToAppConfiguration"
              size="large"
              label="Application Configuration"
              imageMso="AutoArchiveSettings"
              onAction="ButtonClicked"/>
          <button id="GoToAppHelp"
              size="large"
              label="Help"
              imageMso="CreateReportFromWizard"
              onAction="ButtonClicked"/>

Answer (score 2):

You could use a different name for `ButtonClicked` in the Help button.

```xml
<button id="GoToAppHelp" size="large" label="Help" imageMso="CreateReportFromWizard" onAction="ButtonHelpClicked"/>
```

```c
STDMETHOD(ButtonHelpClicked)(IDispatch* ribbon)
{
    //MessageBoxW(NULL,L"Button Clicked!",L"NativeAddin",MB_OK);
    NativeAddIn::Helpme ^helpmeobj = gcnew NativeAddIn::Helpme();
    helpmeobj->ShowDialog();
    return S_OK;
}
```

---

The alternative to this is to use the [`IRibbonControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribboncontrol_members.aspx) context (`ribbon` parameter) and request the control ID to trigger a switch statement. You would just have a single `ButtonClicked` method handling all button clicks.

```c
STDMETHOD(ButtonClicked)(IDispatch* ribbon)
{
    switch (ribbon.Id)
    {
     case "GoToAppConfiguration" : 
        //MessageBoxW(NULL,L"Button Clicked!",L"NativeAddin",MB_OK);
         NativeAddIn::ApplicationConfiguration ^appConfigurationform = gcnew   NativeAddIn::ApplicationConfiguration();
         appConfigurationform->ShowDialog();
         return S_OK;
     case "GoToAppHelp" : 
        //MessageBoxW(NULL,L"Button Clicked!",L"NativeAddin",MB_OK);
        NativeAddIn::Helpme ^helpmeobj = gcnew NativeAddIn::Helpme();
        helpmeobj->ShowDialog();
        return S_OK;
    }   
}
```